# How to execute same AsyncTask number of times after previous execution completed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I wanna execute an AsyncTask in a series as a continue process. As you see the code,i want to call AsyncTask (less than size of ArryList) times. But as per logic i need to follow one condition i need to wait for previous execution completion before calling for next excution, otherwise at next call the execution may refer previous data and store it to server.So how can i achieve this?

```
for(int i=0;i<productsListcart.size();i++)//productsListcart is ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> object,containing data.
{
    HashMap<String, String> success=productsListcart.get(i);
    product_img=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE);
    product_n=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
    product_p=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE);
    product_q=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY);
    new InsertSlipProducts().execute();//AsyncTask calling
}
```

Comment: You can use timer for this purpose.

Comment: @dn_c: may i know some more..please

Comment: Just execute the whole thing in a single AsyncTask ... Why would you use several ones ? Pass the HashMap as argument to the AsyncTask and let it do the job.

Comment: @Gordak: may i know how can i do this?

Comment: Well write an AsyncTask that takes an ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> as argument. In doInBackground,  loop over the list as you do now and execute the code of doInBackground of InsertSlipProducts everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
a roughly written snippet,
just consider the logic

```
int i=0;
if(i<productsListcart.size()){
    HashMap<String, String> success=productsListcart.get(i);
    product_img=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE);
    product_n=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
    product_p=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE);
    product_q=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY);
    new InsertSlipProducts().execute();//AsyncTask calling
    i++;
}


class InsertSlipProducts extends AsyncTask<..>{
/*execute next async task after the current is complete*/
   void onPostExecute(){
       if(i<productsListcart.size()){            
            HashMap<String, String> success=productsListcart.get(i);
            product_img=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_IMAGE);
            product_n=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
            product_p=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE);
            product_q=success.get(TAG_PRODUCT_QUANTITY);
            new InsertSlipProducts().execute();//AsyncTask calling
            i++;
       }
  } 
}
```

Comment: no, it's not fullfill my requirements. here, how i know the 1st execution completed before call to 2nd one.

Comment: obvioiusly u know that, because onPostExecute() is a method of AsyncTask which is called after completing the doInBackground().  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Suppose, i=0, when i go inside all values calculated and task call 1st time for background process. same time my main goes for 2nd execution ie. i=1 and try to calcutate values but in previous background task values get updated due to main 2nd exe. which affect my 1st back task. This is a problem and so that i need to stop my main thread exe. until back task not completed.

Comment: That is what dont call the aysnc task from mainActivity . only call the it for the firsttime as in the first snippet i typed in the answer i.e  dont loop through all the list there it  in MainActivity. Later onPostExecute() execute the same class again only after the current task is finished.

Comment: Thank's bro its solve my problem..........temporary its good for me but looking that its not a good choice to use it for future so allow me more appropriate thing in future.............thanks again for your valuable guidance.